# Handling JSON in JS/ERB template in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, erb

I have no trouble making typical AJAX calls to and from Rails(3) with JSON objects and jQuery-rails (jQuery library plus a special rails.js file).

In one controller, though, I want to RETURN some JSON in an erb template (create.js.erb) after an AJAX call.

I've tried every combination of things in the controller (@object.to_json, '[{"content":"hello world"}]', etc.) and in the template itself (JSON.parse(), single quotes, double quotes, etc.), but the object keeps on rendering like this:

```
'[{&quot;groups&quot;:{},&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2010-09-21T03:49:34Z&quot; ...
```

and as a result, my jQuery code cannot parse it and I get errors.

How do I need to prep my object in the controller, and what erb syntax do I need in the view for it to render as a valid JSON object?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the cause, but you can also try playing around with `html_safe` method. ERB might be escaping your JSON because it thinks it's not html safe. Try calling that method when using the string:

```
@object.to_json.html_safe
```

Comment: Watch out: calling html_safe without escaping can lead to an XSS vulnerability if you're embedding the result in a script tag.

Comment: Check this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3) to see how to use `html_safe` safely

Comment: Note, calling html_safe on this is ONLY dangerous if it can be called on user supplied data like something submitted via a form.  If you're doing it to a dropdown list you supplied on the backend then you're fine.

Answer (score 32):

Using `html_escape` or `raw` alone will leave you [vulnerable to XSS](http://jfire.io/blog/2012/04/30/how-to-securely-bootstrap-json-in-a-rails-view/).

Instead, define a sensible version of the `json_escape` (a.k.a. `j`) helper:

```
module ActionView::Base
  def json_escape(s)
    result = s.to_s.gsub('/', '\/')
    s.html_safe? ? result.html_safe : result
  end

  alias j json_escape
end
```

Use it like this:

```
<script>
  var Accounts = new Backbone.Collection;
  Accounts.reset(<%=j @accounts.to_json.html_safe %>);
  var Projects = new Backbone.Collection;
  Projects.reset(<%=j @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true).html_safe %>);
</script>
```

See [this post](http://jfire.io/blog/2012/04/30/how-to-securely-bootstrap-json-in-a-rails-view/) for further details.

Be aware that there's a [naming conflict](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3578) between `j` aliased to `json_escape` in ERB::Util and `j` aliased to `escape_javascript` in ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper. It's my hope that the JavaScriptHelper alias will be renamed to `js`.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one - it's really shocking how many posts on the internet suggest using html_safe without escaping.

Comment: I believe it should be `class ActionView::Base`, not `module`. Also, is there any reason to not make it html_safe by default? I can't think of any case where you'd want to json_escape and then html_escape.

Comment: Quick question: where should the `module ActionView::Base ... end` definition be placed in the Rails project? Is there a standard path or file for it?

Comment: Rails 4: only `to_json.html_safe` is needed: `'<script>'.to_json`
`=> "\"\\u003cscript\\u003e\""`

Comment: Do you mean `result.html_safe? ? result.html_safe : result`?

Answer (score 1):

To return `json` you have to write your render in the controller as follows:

```
render :json => @object
```

and the `.to_json` will automatically be called.

If you would want to include some relations, you could do the following:

```
render :json => @post.to_json(:include => [:comments, :authors])
```

I am not sure if it would work to use an erb to render your json.

Answer (score 0):

You can call render in your controller, but that will be a problem if you need to possibly render more than a few partials for subsequent dom insertion by the handler. I needed to set multiple html fragments into a hash, and I've been able to return erb which basically uses hash.to_json.html_safe as neutrino suggests above and allows me to render multiple partials in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Only `to_json.html_safe` is needed:

```
> `'<script>'.to_json`
=> "\"\\u003cscript\\u003e\""
```

Patch to make `to_json` respond to `html_safe?` and return `true` automatically:

```
# just use .to_json instead of .to_json.html_safe
ActiveSupport::JSON.class_eval do
  class << self
    def encode_with_html_safe *args
      self.encode_without_html_safe(*args).html_safe
    end
    alias_method_chain :encode, :html_safe
  end
end
```