# Embedding JSON in a Rails 4 JS/ERB template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to embed model data in some javascript in my RoR 4 app. The controller is generating JSON for the model data like so...

```
def my_controller_method
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  @person_json = @person.to_json(only: [:name, :id])
end
```

and I'd like to use that json in my unobtrusive javascript to create javascript objects using JSON.parse()...

```
var personJSON = <%= j @person_json %>;
var person = JSON.parse(personJSON);
```

but the javascript that's generated is...

```
var personJSON = {\&quot;id\&quot;:1,\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;fred\&quot;};
var person = JSON.parse(personJSON);
```

and the javascript is failing silently.

When searching for a solution, I found [this question asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757457/handling-json-in-js-erb-template-in-rails-3), but when I try to use the html_safe method, my rails app crashes saying html_safe is an unknown method.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What about this:

```
var personJSON = <%= @person_json.to_json.html_safe %>
```

or

```
var personJSON = <%= raw @person_json %>
```

I think the last option is better for your particular case.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. I had to wrap it in a escape_javascript call to work. Question, is this susceptible to XSS attacks?

Comment: from rails 3.x there is a concept of HTML-safe strings. `raw` transforms the object to string and then call `html_safe`

Comment: This article explains that using `raw` alone is susceptible to XSS attacks: http://jfire.io/blog/2012/04/30/how-to-securely-bootstrap-json-in-a-rails-view/

Comment: read this article too: http://www.jasonwieringa.com/Learning-About-XSS-Attacks-in-Rails/

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the JSON with `escape_javascript`:

```
var personJSON = "<%= escape_javascript @person_json %>";
```

You can also shorten this to:

```
var personJSON = "<%= j @person_json %>";
```

Comment: thank you. When I do that, my app crashes with the error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for {"id"=>1, "name"=>"fred"}:Hash):`. Your thoughts?

Comment: `as_json` returns a Hash, not JSON.  Use `to_json(only: [:name, :id])` instead.

Comment: Ok, that makes the crash go away, but the resulting js code is still `var personJSON = {\&quot;id\&quot;:1,\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;fred\&quot;};`, which is causing the javascript to fail silently.

Comment: Oh, you need quotes around the string too. I will update the answer.

Comment: Good catch! Still not working though. It throws an exception when parsed, the exception is "Unexpected token &". Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Works great on my rails 5.0

Controller

```
# foo.rb
@data = [{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}, {key3: 'value3'}]
```

View

```
# foo.js.erb
var arr = JSON.parse("<%= escape_javascript(render(inline: @data.to_json)) %>")
console.log(arr) # (2) [Object, Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Jbuilder so in that case I used to do something like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse("<%= j raw render template: '/account/budget_item_elements/show.json.jbuilder' %>");
```

In show.json.jbuilder I could have:

```
json.extract! @budget_item_element, :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to conditionally render text that only had some text in double quotes and this ended up being my solution

```
<%= is_true ? raw(%(This is text not in quotes: "#{@foo.bar.name}")) : "" %>
```

This is a smorgasbord of a lot of other stack overflow posts that when combined end up working for me.