# How to convert &quot; to double qoutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby json object. for example

**In controller**

```
@my_hash = {"5":{"id":5,"name":"ANKLOS","code":"724.9","description":"Ankylosis of spine (Spine Fusion)","title":"ANKLOS - 724.9 - Ankylosis of spine (Spine Fusion)"},"3":{"id":3,"name":"Loren Lipsum","code":"Test","description":"Test t2 stest","title":"Loren Lipsum - Test - Test t2 stest"}}
```

I used **@my_hash** in view. I content comes dynamically from the table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_hash = <%= @my_hash.to_json %>;
</script>
```

but the result of the my_hash is like

```
var diagnosisCodes = {&quot;&quot;:{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;\u0026larr;&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;5&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:5,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;ANKLOS&quot;,&quot;code&quot;:&quot;724.9&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;Ankylosis of spine (Spine Fusion)&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;ANKLOS - 724.9 - Ankylosis of spine (Spine Fusion)&quot;},&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:3,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Loren Lipsum&quot;,&quot;code&quot;:&quot;Test&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;Test t2 stest&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Loren Lipsum - Test - Test t2 stest&quot;}};
```

I need output same like @my_hash. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
@my_hash.to_json.html_safe
```

as said on:
[Handling JSON in JS/ERB template in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757457/handling-json-in-js-erb-template-in-rails-3)